# Using Decodable to decode array of nested objects

Tags: ios, swift, decodable

I started working with Decodable some days ago, and I want to know if is it possible to create the model "Car" without create any more model, having this JSON:

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "car1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "car2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "car3"
        }
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "page": 1,
        "offset": 20
    }
}
```

The only solution that I found is to create a "wrappwer" model like "Response", containing a property as [Cars].

Can somebody confirm me that is possible to decode this JSON just having the "Car" model?

Thank you.

Best regards

Comment: What is wrong to have the Response containing the array of Car? When you request it, you just have to return the Array of Car.

Comment: Any change of the standard workflow is expensive and less efficient. *Any more model* is actually **one** line of code

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Then, is much more efficient to have classes even if they have not important data and you don't need it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
    let str = """

        {
        "cars": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "car1"
        },
        {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "car2"
        },
        {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "car3"
        }
        ],
        "pagination": {
        "page": 1,
        "offset": 20
        }
        }

    """


    do {

        let tr = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(str.utf8), options: []) as! [String:Any] 

        let da = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: tr["cars"]  , options: [])

        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Car].self, from: da)

        print(res)


    }
    catch {

        print(error)
    }
```

---

```
struct Car: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```